# Complex linq with Entity Framework query

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq

How can I write the where clause for this problem?

I want to get a list of businesses where the respective employees have time available to do a specific service on that day.

Examples:
Someone searches for businesses that offer service x on Thursday at 3pm. It needs to check the availability of each employee, bookings and how long it takes to do the service (ServiceEmployee.minutes), which is the booking length.

This is what I have so far:

```
public List<SearchModel.Result> GetServices(SearchModel.Request model)
{
    var geo = DataUtility.GetGeo(model.lat, model.lng);

    var results = (from b in _db.Businesses
                   join ad in _db.Addresses on b.addressId equals ad.addressId
                   join e in _db.Employees on b.businessId equals e.businessId
                   join av in _db.Availabilities on e.employeeId equals av.employeeId
                   join se in _db.ServiceEmployees on e.employeeId equals se.employeeId
                   join s in _db.Services on se.serviceId equals s.serviceId

                   where s.serviceId.Equals(model.serviceId) //service required
                   && av.day.Equals(model.date.DayOfWeek) //day of the week required

                   //how to write the below where clause??

                   //and has at least one slot of time available (no bookings) that will fit the service time length (minutes)
                   //and is not over the employee's shift (Availability.endAt)
                   //

                   && ad.geo.Distance(geo) <= 15000 //15km

                   select new SearchModel.Result
                   {
                       businessId = b.businessId,
                       businessName = b.name,
                       serviceName = s.name,
                       price = se.price, //potentially incorrect
                       time = av.startAt //potentially incorrect
                   }).ToList();

    return results;
}
```

And this is the database structure:
[image]

Comment: Please show/use navigation properties in stead of joins

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted an "answer" to your question on G+, but I thought i would paste it here for more coverage and better formatting:

If I understood you correctly, the main information you need is in the "**Availability**" table. 
You can use that as your starting point and refine your query with further joins. 
The starting (base) SQL query would be something like:

```
SELECT Availabity.EmployeeId FROM Availability
WHERE day = :Query.day AND (EndAt - StartAt) >= :Query.ServiceDuration
```

The result would be a list of all employees with availability at that particular time. 
You can then refine the results to narrow it down to employees that offer the given service, etc.﻿